# Disable default numeric types in compiler

Tags: c++

When creating custom typedefs for integers, is it possible for compiler to warn when you when using a default numeric type?

For example,

```
typedef int_fast32_t    kint;

int_fast32_t test=0;//Would be ok
kint test=0; //Would be ok
int test=0; //Would throw a warning or error
```

We're converting a large project and the default `int` size on platform is `32767` which is causing some issues. This warning would warn a user to not use ints in the code.

If possible, it would be great if this would work on GCC and VC++2012.

Comment: If ther is no other way: `#define int #warning(); int` or just `#define int not-complied-abracadabra` to force error

Comment: No, you can't have a preprocessor directive in a macro definition, and that syntax wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: @Keith But you can use `_Pragma` / `__pragma` for that. It’s not legal to redefine keywords via macros but it will probably work. I’m not sure this is a good idea though, even apart from practical considerations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your "default `int` size" is not 32767... It's probably closer to 2.

Comment: "This warning would warn a user to not use ints in the code." - how about warning the user to write portable code instead?

Comment: You could `grep` your project for `int` followed by whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure gcc has no such option, and I'd be surprised if VC did.

I suggest writing a program that detects references to predefined types in source code, and invoking that tool automatically as part of your build process. It would probably suffice to search for certain keywords.

Be sure you limit this to your own source files; predefined and third-party headers are likely to make extensive use of predefined types.

But I wouldn't make the prohibition absolute. There are a number of standard library functions that use predefined types. For example, in `c = getchar()` it makes no sense to declare `c` as anything other than `int`. And there's no problem for something like `for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i ++) ...`

Ideally, the goal should be to use predefined types *properly*. The language has never guaranteed that an `int` can exceed 32767. (But "proper" use is difficult or impossible to verify automatically.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by doing a replace-all first and then documenting this thoroughly.

You can use a preprocessor directive:

```
#define int use kint instead
```

**Note that technically this is undefined behavior and you'll run into trouble if you do this definition before including third-party headers.**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make bulk replacement `int` -> `old_int_t` at the very beginning of your porting. This way you can continue modifying your code without facing major restrictions and at the same time have access to all places that are not yet updated.

Eventually, at the end of your work, all occurencies of `old_int_t` should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Even if one could somehow undefine the keyword `int`, that would do nothing to prevent usage of that type, since there are many cases where the compiler will end up using that type.  Beyond the obvious cases of integer literals, there are some more subtle cases involving integer promotion.  For example, if `int` happens to be 64 bits, operations between two variables of type `uint32_t` will be performed using type `int` rather than `uint32_t`.  As nice as it would be to be able to specify that some variables represent *numbers* (which should be eagerly promoted when practical) while others represent members of a wrapping *algebraic ring* (which should not be promoted), I know of no facility to do such a thing.  Consequently, `int` is unavoidable.